# Python: unpack init args into member variables cleanly

Tags: python, setattr

Consider the example class below:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a=2, b=0, c=1, d=42):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
```

Is there a clean way to unpack the kwargs into member variables? Perhaps this example is trivial, but imagine a constructor with 17 member variables of long names like `redundant_data_structure_that_we_should_probably_remove`. I'm aware of `setattr()`, for example in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345500/python-unpack-dictionary-inside-a-method), but I don't want to accept **kwargs in the constructor -- that is, I'd like to unpack only the defined member vars `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187082/how-can-you-set-class-attributes-from-variable-arguments-kwargs-in-python help?

Comment: How about `self.__dict__.update(locals())`? Would that set any unwanted attributes?

Comment: @Rawing  Yes.  It sets an unwanted `self.self`.

Comment: Check out the [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked at this before, and concluded there's no nice way to automate out the boilerplate.

Fortunately, you usually don't need it:

- If you have 17 member variables passed in the `__init__`, it's time to refactor.
- If your class is only just a namespace / bag of data, don't use a class in the first place.

If you'd like to experiment with libraries to remove that duplication, check out [`python-fields`](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-fields), or the slightly less magical [`attrs`](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/).

Comment: Any suggestions for a built-in data structure?

Comment: I can't really suggest something without more information about your requirements or use-case.  When in doubt, just use a `dict`.  If you really want getattr-style access instead of getitem-style access, you can use the `Namespace` class that comes for free in the `argparse` module.  And `namedtuple` works fine, really, just don't look at how that's implemented because it's hideous.

Comment: I like the way this addresses the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and focuses the culprit: too many parameters for a single function.